# Android, upload keys and USB debugging via ADB

Tags: android, upload, kivy, adb

I've been trying to start debugging a Kivy app via USB with ADB. It requires an [upload key](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing). The article is just too overwhelming for me. Besides, all I need for now is start debugging, no uploading to Play Store. Is there any step-by-step instruction how to just start debugging locally? Three years ago it didn't require keys.

UPD:

```
ᐅ adb install -r bin/apk/splits/base-armeabi_v7a.apk
Performing Streamed Install
adb: failed to install bin/apk/splits/base-armeabi_v7a.apk: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES: Failed collecting certificates for /data/app/vmdl327565702.tmp/base.apk: Failed to collect certificates from /data/app/vmdl327565702.tmp/base.apk: Attempt to get length of null array]
```

Comment: That article is only for PlayStore uploading (remote signing is only needed for iPhones not foe Android). For local debugging you don't need anything, just connect your phone through adb and press Play in Android Studio (when your app project is loaded). AS will sign the app with an debug key (just a randomly generated key), install it on the phone using `adb install` and then run the app and connect debugger to it.

Comment: Is it really so? See the update on my post. The article says that the upload key is needed as of 2021. There is *Sign your debug build* part. Unfortunately, it's about Android IDE; not my case.

Comment: OK, that part is relevant but as it always happens automatically you don't have to care about it. As I wrote the debug key is nothing special, it is generated automatically by AS and can be replaced at any time (just delete it and it and a new one will be generated). The device accepts any key. Only for app updates it has to be the same key as the APK before was signed with. But as this only applies to debug builds you can simply delete the app and then install the new ap. But as you are just starting this should be not relevant for you at the moment.

Comment: I'm happy to hear that the issue isn't relevant. I just want the fatal error to go away. Look at the update in case you have not seen it. This is the very first attempt, yes. What do I have to do?